# boolean value in onRequestPermissionsResult changes but MainActivity uses old boolean value

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-runtime

I have a Boolean value that I am updating in the onRequestPermissionsResult method if I'm granted the permissions. And later after call to my checkPermission method I am checking the value of boolean.
The value of boolean is changing in the onRequestPermissionsResult but before the change happens the MainActivity code runs and uses the old value.
What is the problem that MainActivity is not waiting for the onRequestPermissionsResult to end and then proceed to use the recent value of the boolean.

Also I am running the code on my mobile that have almost 300 contacts but the app only show one same random contact all the time.

```
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);

    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

    Cursor data = null;

    getPermissionStatus();

    //the if statement does not waits for the onRequestPermissionsResult to ends

    if (permissionGranted) {
        data = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, mSelectionColumns,
                null, null, null);
        if (data != null && data.getCount() > 0) {
            while (data.moveToNext()) {
                textView.setText(data.getString(
                        data.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME))
                        + "\t " +"\n");
            }
        } else
            Toast.makeText(this, "No data...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else
        Toast.makeText(this, "Permission not granted.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    if (data != null) {
        data.close();
    }

}

public void getPermissionStatus() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) !=
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Requesting...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                REQ_CODE_READ_CONTACTS);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {

    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQ_CODE_READ_CONTACTS:
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                //Main activity should these value of the permissinGranted
                permissionGranted = true;
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Granted...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                permissionGranted = false;
            }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the conditional statement with `if (permissionGranted)` ... runs right after `requestPermissions()`, and due to threading (main), the following lines of code would run right after as in it'd run even before the permission dialog is displayed. That said, you'd want to set up querying the database in a method where it'd be invoked during runtime in the main thread for Android versions below 6.0 and upon granting permissions in the `onRequestPermissionsResult()` callback method for Android 6.0 and above.

Also, remember that [requesting permissions at runtime is only for Android 6.0 and above](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html), so consider reconfiguring your conditional statement since your boolean flag, `permissionGranted`, will always be false for versions lower than 6.0.

Comment: Thanks. I understand. This solved my issue.
But technically my code should work isn't it? And also why I am seeing only one contact in my app?

Comment: @SAIFI369 Well, I could see the code lines after `getPermissionStatus()` running properly for versions below Android 6.0 as well as runtimes AFTER granting the permission from the previous session as mentioned in my updated answer.

Comment: @SAIFI369 As far as the database returning only one row of data goes, I'm not entirely sure based on the code snippets you've posted since the scope of SQLite databases is quite broad. Consider addressing this in a new question. For starters, have you tried logging the count of your Cursor data to see how many rows are currently in the database?

Comment: Thanks a lot...this solved my problem and very well explained